# Zoho Data Insert Error: "Unable to process your request. Please verify whether you have entered proper method name,parameter and parameter values."

Tags: php, api, zoho

I want to Insert Data to zoho using insertRecords method, but unfortunately i got this error.

Here is my code:

```
$insertArrayCon = array();
$zohoData = array();

$module = 'Contacts';
$insertArrayCon['First Name'] = trim($_REQUEST['con_first_name_v']);
$insertArrayCon['Last Name'] = trim($_REQUEST['con_last_name_v']);
$insertArrayCon['Email'] = trim($_REQUEST['con_email_v']);
$insertArrayCon['Mobile'] = trim($_REQUEST['con_mobile_v']);
$zohoData[0] = $insertArrayCon;
$insertZoho = $this->Nzoho->insertRecords($zohoData, $module);
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: try this : `Setup-->Extensions & APIs-->APIs-->CRM API-->Click on Gear Icon-->Authentication Token Regeneration`

Answer (score 0):

You check your all parameter's Exe- Module Name, Authentication Token, scope, xmlData,Data format, version, CRM field type, Post URL ......

Flow this documentation for create your post data -
[insertRecords Method](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/insertrecords.html)

If you sure your data is ok you can try this process-
This process provided from Zoho forum..

Zoho forums Link : [Zoho CRM->Zoho CRM Developer APIs](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/unable-to-process-your-request-please-verify-whether-you-have-entered-proper-method-name-parameter-and-parameter-values)

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with the parameters.

Comment: Welcome, 
Here https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/ you get Zoho API documentation..